# How can I implement this one line XAML programmatically in WPF code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

How can I implement this one line XAML programmatically in code?  (as I'm needing to create the radio buttons on the fly, but what them to having bindings)

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Mode, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Proxy}">Proxy</RadioButton>
```

I've got it to here (see below) so far, but now I'm struggling re how to get the binding to be hooked up. I've made a guess/assumption I should be using the Binding class...

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> @interface in interfaces)
    {
        // RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Mode, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Proxy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , Mode=TwoWay}">Proxy</RadioButton>

        // Create Radio Button
        var newRb = new RadioButton();
        newRb.Name = "I" + @interface.Key.ToString();
        newRb.GroupName = "InterfaceGroup";
        newRb.Content = @interface.Value;

        // Binding
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = "Interface";
        binding.Converter = new RadioBoolToIntConverter();
        binding.ConverterParameter = @interface.Key;

        // STUCK HERE - RE HOW TO GET THE BINDING TO BE APPLIED TO THE RADIO BUTTON

        InterfacesRadioButtons.Children.Add(newRb);
    }
```

And for background the model class with dependency object:

```
public class ConfigWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    // Interface Number 
    public int Interface
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(InterfaceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InterfaceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InterfaceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Interface", typeof(int), typeof(ConfigWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
newRb.SetBinding(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
```

Alternatively:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(radioButton, RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
```